# Asymptotic behavior of the function $e^{- \lambda t^2}$ when $\lambda$ is small

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I wish to prove that when $\lambda$ is taken to be very small
$$  \left| e^{- \lambda t^2} - \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(- \lambda t^2)^n}{n!} \right| = O(e^{-\frac{a}{\lambda}})$$
for some constant $a \in \mathbb{R} : a > 0$. Earlier I proved that
$$ \left| e^{- \lambda t^2} - \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(- \lambda t^2)^n}{n!} \right| \leq \frac{(\lambda t^2)^{N+1}}{(N+1)!}$$
I was given the hint that we may "choose" $N$ such that $N = O(1/\lambda)$, but I am not exactly sure how to use this hint. I am not even sure what $\lambda$ is small means mathematically, nor do I see how I am going to be able to get an exponential decay term with $\lambda$ in it. My first thought was to try and somehow force the factorial of $1/\lambda$ and use the Sterling approximation for $(1/\lambda)!$ but I am unable to evaluate the above inequalities to make use of it.

Comment: hint: Set $N=\frac{a}{\lambda}$   where $a$ is some positive constant and use stirlings approximation ($\lambda\rightarrow 0 $)

Comment: Stirling's approximation has the property that  $n! \propto e^{-n}$ among other proportionalities. Since $(N+1)!$ is in the denominator then we would be left with $O(e^{a/\lambda})$ instead of a negative exponent.

Comment: ah ok sorry that was too fast...but with negative $a$ it should work out right?

Comment: No problem, and yes it would.

Comment: Ok, are you satisfied with this argument, or do have any concers?

Comment: The constant $a$ must be a positive number, so your argument doesn't worky, sorry.

Comment: The point is i think, that $O(1/\lambda)$ here really means $-O(1/\lambda)$ so my point would be valid. I guess it is just a problem with sloppy notation.